# Does [UIView removeFromSuperview] also remove its children views recursively?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have a view hierarchy that I need to remove entirely. Is it okay to just call `removeFromSuperview` on the top parent view or do I need to visit each child node recursively and remove it individually?

**Edit**: Just to clarify, I understand that removing the parent physically removes the children from view, but does that also decrease their ref-counts appropriately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All subviews belong to the view; so, when you remove a view from it's superview - it is removed with all it's subviews.

Comment: Does it also decrease reference counts of the children views?

Comment: Yes, of course. The sub-views are owned by NSMutableArray 'subviews' of UIView, so when UIView instance is deallocated, it releases the NSMutableArray instance. And if that one is deallocated, all items, stored in this array, will be sent with release, that will decrease the refcount of subviews

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can think of views as a tree structure. So if you tell a view to be removed from the super view, the whole structure will be removed.

For example: A `UIButton` is actually a view which contains an `UILabel` which displays the title of the button. So you can do this `[myUIButton removeFromSuperview];`, which will remove the button and its own view hierarchy (including the button's containing UILabel).

**Remark**: If you only want to hide/and show a view you can also set its `hidden` property to `YES` or `NO` instead of removing the view from the view hierarchy. Like this it is easy to display the view again.

Answer (score 2):

No, removing a view doesn't do anything to it's child views (but of course they will no longer be drawn as they aren't in the view hierarchy any more).

Of course, if you remove a view and have no other strong references to it, it may be deallocated at some point in the future (although you shouldn't care about this or assume that there are no other references). **When** and **if** it is deallocated it will remove it's child views and release them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on top parent view.